# Override footer content with custom cms blocks?

Tags: magento2, custom, cms, footer, luma-theme

Is there a way to "delete" all current footer content, and put a single cms block in there?

I want to manage all its content in a simple cms block. 
Designing a custom footer seems to be very complicated when using the regular xml.

Comment: Refer this link for customize footer.
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117669/customize-footer-in-magento2/145328#145328

Answer (score 0):

Try this layout in your module

add default.xml in your module app\code\Vendorname\Modulename\view\frontend\layout\default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="footer" remove="true">
        <referenceContainer name="footer-container">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="your_footer_cms_block_id">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">your_footer_cms_block_id</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```