# Magento 2 website no longer loads after running compile command

Tags: magento2, error, footer, footer-links

I'm currently developing a website on a local installation of Magento 2.

I was following advice on how to add a **.phtml** file to my pages.
[Customize Footer in magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/117669/customize-footer-in-magento2/193461)

I followed one solution that advised to run compile command after making the changes.

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

I did this and now my Magento 2 website no longer loads.

I'm not sure what has happened or how to fix it.

In system.log I'm only seeing the following:

```
[2020-06-25 00:01:47] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/_view/en_GB/Magento_Theme/favicon.ico' [] []
[2020-06-25 00:01:47] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file for 'frontend/_view/en_GB/Magento_Theme/favicon.ico' [] []
```

Can I undo this command?

Any solution would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: try to re run the upgrade command and redeploy static contents and also flush the cache after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please run below command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento cache:flush

php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Answer (score 0):

Run Magento upgrade, compile, and deploy commands as below.

> Upgrade

```
php bin/magento s:up
```

> Compile

```
php bin/magento s:d:c
```

> Deploy static content

```
php bin/magento s:s:d
```

Make sure to give proper permissions fo folders and directories.

Comment: I followed the accepted answer here:
[link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94502/magento2-re-generate-css-file-in-pub-static-folder)

The Admin Panel and website now load but the functionality and images are broken.

I believe I need to set the folder and directories permissions but I'm using XAMPP for Windows so I'm not sure how to run the necessary commands.

The find command (as described here) doesn't work in XAMPP:
[link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91870/magento-2-folder-file-permissions)